# Парсинг данных из Postgresql в json файл с помощью java

Tags: java, json, postgresql

Требуется вытащить из БД postgresql одну таблицу в файл json с помощью программы на java.

У меня получилось только создать запрос, который выводит данные в нужном мне виде через консоль psql

```
(select row_to_json(t)  from(select * from cars) as t)
```

но в программе на java не выходит, вот что я пытаюсь делать:

```
String sql = "select row_to_json(t) " +
                    "into outfile 'C:\\Users\\79885\\IdeaProjects\\untitled6\\my_file.json' from(select * from cars) as t";

                stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Вся программа:
PS. в данной программе работают другие команды sql (create, input into, etc.)

```
import org.postgresql.util.PSQLException;

import java.sql.*;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class PostgreSQLJDBC {
    public static void main( String args[] ) {
        Connection c = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test", "postgres", "postgres");
            System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

            stmt = c.createStatement();
            String sql = "select row_to_json(t) " +
                    "into outfile 'C:\\Users\\79885\\IdeaProjects\\untitled6\\my_file.json' from(select * from cars) as t";
            System.out.println(sql);
                stmt.executeUpdate(sql);


            stmt.close();
            c.close();
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            System.err.println( e.getClass().getName()+": "+ e.getMessage() );
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Table created successfully");
    }
}
```

Получаю ошибку:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "'C:\Users\79885\IdeaProjects\untitled6\my_file.json'")
Позиция: 36

Думаю, что неправильно пытаюсь создать/обратиться к файлу, подскажите, как правильно это делается

[image: На изображении видны изменения (Добавлены одинарные кавычки 'C...json' и пробел между '.json .... from']

Comment: да, неправильно. после outfile должен быть указан в качестве имени файла один параметр, а у вас их два:

C:\\Users\\79885\\IdeaProjects\\untitled6\\json

и

files\\my1_file.json

Comment: В такое уныние ввергают такие вопросы :(. Ну выведите вы свою переменную `sql` в консоль (или в отладчике посмотрите содержимое). Не хватает пробела между `.json` и `from`.

Comment: @RabbanKeyak , параметр один, если угодно, директорию `json files` можно вообще опустить и положить `my_file.json` в корневую папку проекта `untitled6`. Суть дела не меняется, а отладчик ругается на ошибку синтаксиса около 'C' .  Мой вопрос в целом был о том, как правильно вывести табличку из psql в json файл, а пример кода я привел просто в качестве демострации своей попытки. Можете указать на недостатки или ошибки, чтобы я начал заново, но уже с умом

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov , данная правка тоже не помогла, видимо, проблема в том, что я изначально что-то делаю не так. Как раз чтобы это понять и задал вопрос, а не просто чтобы мне помогли исправить код и я его благополучно сдал. Может быть я вопрос неправильно сформулировал. Все же, он остается актульным и я буду рад получить ответ

Comment: Не стесняйтесь редактировать вопрос столько раз, сколько нужно. Добавили пробел - отредактируйте вопрос, покажите что сделали и что получаете теперь.

Comment: Путь к файлу возьмите в одинарные кавычки: `'C:...json'`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, добавил изображение, где все видно, пробел исправил, кавычки добавил

Answer (score 0):

Теперь нужно скопировать запрос из консоли IDEA и вставить его в консоль Постгресса. И посмотреть, что тот скажет.
Может быть путь не существует? Попробуйте попроще путь.

Answer (score 0):

Я не спец по Postgres, но откуда вы взяли такой синтаксис?

[select ... into ...](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-selectinto.html) используется для вставки в *таблицу*, но не в файл.

И что означает `outfile`? Во многих примерах sql-запросов этот параметр используется для указания имени файла. То есть вместо `outfile` должно быть определённое значение, а само это слово не нужно.

[COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) - очевидно, вам нужна эта команда. Она позволяет копировать данные в файл.

Но этой командой не получится с сервера записать файла на клиенте.

---

У вас в коде применяется `row_to_json`. Если использовать именно это функцию, то запрос должен выглядеть просто:

```
select row_to_json(*) from cars
```

И в коде Java [стандартным](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/query.html) способом в цикле читаем значения и пишем в файл.

---

Другой вариант. Вернее, варианты. Смотрите https://stackoverflow.com/a/24006432/5045688.

Кратко:

```
SELECT json_agg(t) FROM t
```

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку! Изначально я пытался использовать именно COPY TO, на что получал такую ошибку: "COPY TO указывает серверному процессу PostgreSQL записать данные в файл.. Возможно, на самом деле вам нужно клиентское средство, например, \copy в psql."

Comment: Пробовал пользоваться \copy, но так и не докопался до рабочего варианта синтаксиса

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать